# Is Proxima Nova a web safe font?

Tags: website-design, fonts, typography, web-safe

I've been asked to replace the font we use on the web and mobile apps with Proxima Nova. I wanted to ask the community if any of you know if Promima Nova is a web safe font?. Thanks.

Comment: It's also available on Typekit.

Answer (score 6):

If by "web safe" you mean common on all platforms, then No. It is not. You will have to use @font-face with a web and/or app license.

Comment: Ah Thanks. This is exactly what i was looking for.